# Como enviar token do browser para o servidor?

Tags: php, token, jwt

Como enviar o token jwt do browser para o servidor php a cada requisição? Toda vez que eu estudo sobre a utilização de um token apenas mostra como criar, não como utilizar de fato, na imagem a baixo mostra que se devolve o token ao servidor em toda requisição, mas como fazer isso, utilizando PHP?
[image]

Se possível, poderia mandar um exemplo de uso do token!

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso o `satellizer` que faz isso pra mim, nem me preocupo onde devo salvar ou não. Ele envia o token do `JWT` para o server, e salvar o token no navegador.

Segue o link: [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, muito obrigado!

Comment: Só é possível usar o token com uma SPA?

Comment: Não, você pode pegar o token retornado da API e salvar no navegador (localhistory) por exemplo.

Comment: E como eu envio ao server para autenticar sempre que mudar de página?